# Illegal byte sequence error

Tags: bash, unix, join, awk

while

```
join -t',' -1 1 -2 1 <(sort -t, -k1 data.csv) <(sort -t, -k1 metadata.csv) > new.csv
```

I am getting Illegal byte sequence error.
In both data.csv and metadata.csv, first field is common and it is like `"TFGHTEW123"`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
LANG=C join -t',' -1 1 -2 1 <(LANG=C sort -t, -k1 data.csv) <(LANG=C sort -t, -k1 metadata.csv) > new.csv
```